# Can it be the some energy will remain after long time? Capacitors and resistors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrical-resistance, capacitance

[image]

My question is pretty simple, but I'll have to describe the problem in order to ask it:

We have a an RC circuit as we can see in the picture.
The given details are:

the resistance of the resistor $ R $, and $ C_1,C_2 $ are parallel plates capacitors, such that the area of the capacitor's $ C_1 $ plates is $ A $, and the area of the capacitor's $ C_2 $ plates is 5A.

The space between 2 plates is the same for both capacitors and equals $ d $

In addition, it is given that at $ t=0 $ the $ C_1 $ capacitor is charged with $ Q $ and the $ C_2 $ capacitor charged with $ Q_2 $ .

Now, we close the circuit and wait a long time untill the system reach equilibrium, and I should say what is the change in the energy after this long time.

Now, I did my calculations and found an expression for the lost energy (the energy becomes heat energy because of the resistor), and **my question is**:

After a very long time, can it be that some electric energy will remain in the system? because I think that all of the electric energy in the system will turn eventually into heat energy since we have the resistor in the system and we wait long time.

But apparently my answer to this question is wrong and I cannot understand why.

That was pretty much my question, from now on I'll describe my calculations:

we had a few choices (it was an american test) and the right answer according to the TA:

"The change in the energy would be $ \frac{3dQ^{2}}{20\varepsilon_{0}A} $"

My answer is:

"The change in the energy would be $ \frac{9dQ^{2}}{10\varepsilon_{0}A} $ And her's the actual calculations:

Since we are talking about parallel plates capacitors, we can use the formula to capacitance given by:

$ C=\frac{\varepsilon_{0}A}{d} $.

Thus,  $ C_{1}=\frac{\varepsilon_{0}A}{d},C_{2}=\frac{5\varepsilon_{0}A}{d} $.

Now Im gonna use the formula to the electric energy stored in capacitance given by:

$ U_{E}=\frac{Q^{2}}{2C} $.

Thus the energy stored in $ C_1 $  given by:

$ \frac{dQ^{2}}{2\varepsilon_{0}A} $, and the energy stored in $ C_2 $ given by :

$ \frac{4dQ^{2}}{10\varepsilon_{0}A} $, all in all, the energy we have at $ t=0 $ given by

$ \frac{9dQ^{2}}{10\varepsilon_{0}A} $, and I claim that all of this energy would be wasted on the resistor.

Its very important for me to understand if its possible that in equilibrium state some electric energy will remain.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "because I think that all of the electric energy in the system will turn eventually into heat energy since we have the resistor in the system and we wait long time." Why would you think that? Current  will cease to flow when the voltages on the capacitors are equal. That voltage need not be zero.

Comment: Also, the test answer has $d$ in it. The implication is that the plate separation for both capacitors is the same, =$d$. But that assumption was not stated in your description of the problem.

Comment: @Bob_D If we'll take a circuits with 2 charged capacitors connected in parallel, and a resistor. The capacitors wouldnt the capacitors disxharge completly?

Comment: Oh sorry. I will edit.

Comment: The two capacitors would not necessarily  discharge completely. That would only be the case if the voltage on both capacitors became zero. Current stops when the voltage become equal and that is not necessarily zero voltage.

Comment: @Bob D But 2 capacitors that connected in parallel always has the same voltage

Comment: Before the switch is closed the voltages may be different. If they were equal before the switch is closed, no current would flow after the switch is closed and no energy would be dissipated in the resistor. At the instant the switch is closed, the difference between the voltages of the capacitors when the switch was open will equal the voltage drop across the resistor, per Kirchhoff's voltage law.

Comment: @FreeZe, these 2 capacitors are not connected in parallel.

Comment: Also, isn't the charge on C2 supposed to $2Q$, and not $Q_2$ in order for the answer to make sense?

Comment: You may be thinking that energy could not remain in the system forever and it probably won't.  Real capacitors will probably leak and discharge.  However, I assume that the components are assumed to be ideal and so this won't occur.  The only loss will be if current flows through the resistor.

Comment: @badjohn I think we need to assume the problem involves ideal (leakless) capacitors

Comment: @BobD Yes, I would think so too but I thought that this might be why the OP felt that the situation would not happen.

Comment: @badjohn I see what you mean that could have been why. But seeing the OPs follow up questions it becomes clear, at least to me, was the misunderstanding af the concept of conservation of charge

Comment: @BobD Indeed, or maybe a bit of both.  Anyway, you seem to have cleared it up with your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> $ \frac{9dQ^{2}}{10\varepsilon_{0}A} $, and I claim that all of this
> energy would be wasted on the resistor.

This is where you go wrong. Some electrostatic potential energy will remain in the circuit. The only way there would be no remaining potential energy is if the voltages on both capacitors was zero after a long time. But that cannot happen due to the requirement of conservation of charge. After a long time there will still be a total charge of $Q+Q_2$ distributed between the two capacitors.

This is as far as I can go as the policy on this site is to not provide solutions to homework and exercise questions.

> I see. Of course, I do not seek after a full solution, just to
> understand the idea. As a last question, what happens when we have a
> single charged capacitor and the resistor circuit. The voltage will be
> 0 after long time and the capacitor will discharge completely. In that
> case, where the charge goes? Why wouldn't it be conserved?

There is still conservation of charge. Both before and after connecting the capacitor to the resistor, the net charge on the capacitor as a whole is zero. The only difference is before discharging the total charge on the capacitor is separated into + charge on one plate and - charge on the other, creating a potential difference. After discharging through the resistor, there is an equal amount of + and - charge on each plate because there is no longer a voltage difference when the current ceases. All of the energy stored in the capacitor is lost as heat in the resistor, but there is no loss of total charge. Charge is conserved.

The situation is different for the two capacitors and resistor of your example. The capacitor with the higher voltage can use part of its potential energy to charge the capacitor with the lower voltage after closing the switch so there  can be net positive and negative charge on each plate.

You can determine the final voltages and charges on each capacitor and the energy dissipated in the resistor by applying the following constraints:

(1) Conservation of charge, i.e., $Q_{1}+Q_{2}=Q_{before}$

(2) For current to cease, $V_{1}=V_{2}$

(3) For conservation of energy, $I^{2}Rt=PE_{f}-PE_{i}$

Hope this helps.

Comment: I see. Ofcourse, I do not seek after a full solution, just to understand the idea. As a last question, what happans when we have a single charged capacitor and thd resistor circuit. The voltage will be 0 after long time and the capacitor will dischatge completly. In that case, where the charge goes? Why wouldnt it be conserved?

Comment: @FreeZe I have revised my answer to address your follow up question. Hope it helps.